# Use custom gradle task

Tags: groovy, gradle

I've created custom task, published in ivy repository and now I want to use it. This is how I do it:

```
configurations {
    customTask {
        transitive = false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    ivy  {
        url 'http://my.ivy.rep/ivyrep/shared'
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    customTask 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.8.4'
    customTask 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.49'
    customTask group: 'pl.com', name:'MyCustomTask', version:'0.9', configuration: 'runtime'
}

task buildInstaller(type: eu.company.gradle.MyCustomTask) {
    ...
}
```

And this is my custom task:

```
package eu.company.gradle
class MyCustomTask extends DefaultTask {

    public MyCustomTask() {}

    @TaskAction
    def build() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Dependencies are downloaded but when I want to run 'buildInstaller' task I get this error:

```
Could not find property 'pl' on root project 'Configurable installer'.
```

It looks like my jar isn't in classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From "56.3.1. Using your task class in another project" in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url uri('../repo')
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.gradle', name: 'customPlugin', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

task greeting(type: org.gradle.GreetingTask) {
    greeting = 'howdy!'
}
```

The full Gradle distribution has the complete sample code.

Comment: Ok, thanks but my build works in that way so where is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't. Note the `buildscript` block.